# How to add "new" element/objects s to a list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, react-native

Let's say I have a List of objects in javascript.

```js
demoList = [
 {
  name: "first object",
  value: "first value",
  year: "first year"
 },
 {
  name: "second object",
  value: "second value",
  year: "second year"
 },
 {
  name: "third object",
  value: "third value",
  year: "third year"
 },
 {
  name: "fourth object",
  value: "fourth value",
  year: "fourth year"
 },
]
```

Now I make some API call and get more data like ...

```js
moreData = [
 {
  name: "first object",
  value: "first value",
  year: "first year"
 },
 {
  name: "sixth object",
  value: "sixth value",
  year: "sixth year"
 },
 {
  name: "seventh object",
  value: "seventh value",
  year: "seventh year"
 },
]
```

I want to add the new objects i.e the sixth and seventh to my existing demoList and discard the existing object i.e. first object. How do I achieve this in javascript with less time complexity?
No I cannot use sets. Also let's just say the criteria for comparison is the name. Other values can be same.

Comment: Why can't you use a `Set`?

Comment: I can't use set because I need to pass this data to a flatlist: (

Comment: You can keep a Set of names and it will be faster to process than an array of unique names since you are concerned about time complexity.  Not sure what flatlist to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can check the result by Array.prototype.find() method and then push it.

```js
const demoList = [{
    name: "first object",
    value: "first value",
    year: "first year"
  },
  {
    name: "second object",
    value: "second value",
    year: "second year"
  },
  {
    name: "third object",
    value: "third value",
    year: "third year"
  },
  {
    name: "fourth object",
    value: "fourth value",
    year: "fourth year"
  },
];

const moreData = [{
    name: "first object",
    value: "first value",
    year: "first year"
  },
  {
    name: "sixth object",
    value: "sixth value",
    year: "sixth year"
  },
  {
    name: "seventh object",
    value: "seventh value",
    year: "seventh year"
  },
]

const mergeObjectsByName = (org, more) => {
  const res = [...org];
  for (let m of more) {
    if (res.find(it => it.name === m.name)) continue;
    res.push(m)
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(mergeObjectsByName(demoList, moreData));
```

Comment: Do you think it will perform well in lists with 100+ objects?

Comment: Sure, it works 100+ because the complexity will be orgArray.length * moreArray.length
So 100 * 100 works without any problem

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that

```
demoList = [...demoList, ...moreData];
```

I assumed you will get a unique array of object from API if the data will not unique so you can remove the duplicate value

```
demoList = [...demoList, ...moreData];
demoList = demoList.filter((v,i,a)=> a.findIndex(t=>(t.name === v.name))===i)
```

Answer (score 1):

name is unique key -> convert initial array to object with name keys

```
const result = {};
demoList.forEach(e => result[e.name] = e});
moreData.forEach(e => {
  if (result[e.name] === undefined ){
    result[e.name] = e;
  }
})

const resultList = Object.values(result);
```

I don't understand, you want merge object what keys coincided ? If yes:

```
  moreData.forEach(e => {
  if (result[e.name] === undefined ){
    result[e.name] = e;
  } else {
    result[e.name] = { ...result[e.name], ...e };
  }
})
```